# django model get field method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a requirement, when a field say `Price` in a django model `Lead` is accessed I have to apply some business logic and update the price.

I can accomplish in Serializers / Views. However this object is accessed by several views and hence its not a viable design to have a code in several place.

So i'm looking for a way where i can get control like `get_price(self)`.

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField(_('price'), default=10)

    def get_price(self):
    ''' Looking for something like this '''
    .. Logic ...
    return self.price
```

`get_price` to be called when any serializers/ views access this model. The issue is `get_price` is not getting invoked when this model is accessed.

Comment: `return self.price` inside your `get_price()` ?

Comment: the issue is get_price is not getting invoked when this model is accessed ?

Comment: It won't. You have to call `get_price()` explicitly. I don't know if there's any method to be invoked whenever the model is accessed.

Comment: Yeah thats what i found. if its a serializer then we can have a method. so on access of serializer we can update. however in this way I have to update atleast 3 serialzier, which is not a great design. so looking for django models

Comment: So you want to update price field when access to Lead Object?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the price when some one get's the value. However will not change if someone set's it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the property method of the class. Which will access through the objects. You can just include that fields in the serializer.

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField(_('price'), default=10)

   @property
   def total_price(self):
      ''' Looking for something like this '''
      .. Logic ...
      return self.price
```

now you can include total_prcie field in serializer.

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Lead
          fields = ('total_prize', )
```

Comment: I'm ok with this. but the only issue with this solution is we have to edit the serializers. What i'm looking for is a solution without touching serializers. This object will be accessed by several other objects, So would wish this logic to be in one place

Answer (score 0):

I completed this task in a very different way,  I had to create another table known as TrackLead Table to track when changes where made.

Later in `__init__` function i updated the price field when required. I didnt find anyother way to complete it. However its working now .